# multithreading issues for amazon s3 get requests

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-s3

I am trying to list the objects from s3 bucket which has very large data.
I am using "listObjects" method in multiple threads (50 to 100 threads). For each thread, I am giving commonPrefix which the API will list all the objects under that commonprefix.
I have to use many threads in pull the large data in reasonable time. So I defined 100 threads but I am facing the following exceptions:

1. javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake
2. java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
3. java.net.SocketException: read timed out

I want to know the efficient use of multithreads for amazon s3 requests

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Amazon doesn't want you to do 100 queries at a time.

In addition 100 connections will put a huge strain on the user's network connection and probably slow down the whole thing more than you think, at least on some systems.

It would be smarter to use a NIO [Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) instead of 100 threads.

Comment: I am very much new to java NIO. Since I only send the request and socket connections are handled by amazon API itself, can we still use Selectors here?

Comment: If the entire connection is handled by a (Java) API then probably not. As far as I understood your question I thought you were doing the calls on your own and use a REST-API.